# Json get graph api permissions

Tags: php

Not working code:

```
$izincikcik = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=YOURTOKENCODE');
$json = json_decode($izincikcik, true);
$izinvarmi = $json["data"]["publish_stream"];
echo "$izinvarmi";
```

Comment: **1)** what output you will receive? **2)** maybe you are not allowed to use `file_get_contents()` function in your server for connect to another server (try to replace with `curl` connection)

Comment: what output you've receive with curl usage?

Comment: http://byvolkan.com/withcurl.txt

Comment: White Screen No output